# In case of expandableListView while expanding the group the children are getting expanded below the bottom bar

Tags: android

I have a Tab and for that my layout is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/classified_bg"
    tools:context=".activities.HomepageActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/expandableListViewMarginStart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/expandableListViewMarginStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/expandableListViewMarginTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/group_item_spacing"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My group count is big and while expanding a group which is the last visible group in the list(more are there which are currently not fitting the screen), the children expands below the bottom bar thus are not visible until I scrolled. What I want is that children become visible in the screen while expanding. Please help me here. I am very new to android development

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to read the parent or child names so I am just going to post the java class and xml code that I used in my app and you can see through the way I have coded in my java class.This might solve your problem.

FoodMenu.java

```
public class FoodMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader ;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
public static ArrayAdapter<String> Aadapter ;

public static  ArrayList<String> list = null;

Button cart;

public static String[] array = new String[50];
int No_of_items = 0;
public static int total = 0 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_menu);

   expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.Explv);

   prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
 }

  private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("North Indian");
    listDataHeader.add("South Indian");
    listDataHeader.add("Gujarati");
    listDataHeader.add("Punjabi");
    listDataHeader.add("Fast Food");
    listDataHeader.add("Desert");


    // Adding child data
    List<String> Ni = new ArrayList<String>();
    Ni.add("Dum Aloo (Rs.50)");
    Ni.add("Poha (Rs.40)");
    Ni.add("Fara (Rs.60)");
    Ni.add("Paneer Butter Masala (Rs.160)");
    Ni.add("Cholle Puri (Rs.150)");
    Ni.add("Dahi Vada (Rs.150)");


    List<String> Si = new ArrayList<String>();
    Si.add("Dosa (Rs.150)");
    Si.add("Idli (Rs.100)");
    Si.add("Biryani (Rs.150)");
    Si.add("Paal Payasam (Rs.150)");
    Si.add("Coorgi Pandi Curry (Rs.75)");
    Si.add("Upma (Rs.50)");


    List<String> G = new ArrayList<String>();
    G.add("Gujarati Thali (Rs.250)");
    G.add("Puran Poli (Rs.80)");
    G.add("Khaman Dhokla (Rs.90)");
    G.add("Handvo (Rs.70)");
    G.add("Sukhadi (Rs.70)");


    List<String> P = new ArrayList<String>();
    P.add("Naan (Rs.50)");
    P.add("Paratha (Rs.50)");
    P.add("Paneer Tikka (Rs.150)");
    P.add("Paneer Bhurji (Rs.150)");
    P.add("Veg Jaipuri (Rs.150)");
    P.add("Veg Hydrabadi (Rs.150)");

    List<String> FF = new ArrayList<String>();
    FF.add("Pizza (Rs.250)");
    FF.add("Sandwich (Rs.150)");
    FF.add("Hotdog (Rs.60)");
    FF.add("French Fries (Rs.90)");
    FF.add("Mccain (Rs.90)");
    FF.add("Burger (Rs.90)");

    List<String> D = new ArrayList<String>();
    D.add("Ice Cream (Rs.50)");
    D.add("Brownie (Rs.150)");
    D.add("Chaas (Rs.30)");
    D.add("Lassi (Rs.50)");
    D.add("Colddrink (Rs.40)");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Ni); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Si);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), G);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), P);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), FF);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), D);
}
}
```

food_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">

<TextView
    android:text="Menu"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="490dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/Explv"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```